# How does the math for this line of recursion work?

Tags: c

I understand how the program runs, i just have trouble understand this single line.

```
return recursion(m + 2) + m + recursion(m + 1);
```

I have trouble understanding the math for it

```
#include<stdio.h>

int recursion(int m)
{
    if(m == 10)
        return 2;
    else if(m == 11)
        return 1;
    else
        return recursion(m + 2) + m + recursion(m + 1);
}

int main()
{
    int x;

    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d\n", recursion(x));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for editing it

Comment: The math is derived right away: `f(10)=2, f(11)=1, f(x) = f(x+2) + x + f(x+1) for x other than 10 or 11`

Comment: I recommend *not* running this for 12 or higher.

Comment: In order to understand the maths, try yourself on paper: start with x=9, then try x=8 and so on. Note: for m>11 your program will diverge,  and you will experience a crash related to this site's name. ;)

Comment: I just wrote this in python. Got ```segmentation fault (core dumped)``` for number ```12``` while I also had to increase max recursion depth to 200,000